# expand oracle table fields linearly

Tags: sql, database, string, oracle, recursive-query

I have the following table in oracle:

```
ID    field_1    field_2
1       1-5        1-5
1      20-30      55-65
2       1-8       10-17
2      66-72      80-86
```

I need to convert this table to the following format where field_1 and field_2 must be matched linearly:

```
   ID   field_1  field_2
    1      1       1
    1      2       2
    1      3       3
    1      4       4
    1      5       5
    1      20      55
    1      21      56
    1      22      57
    1      23      58
    1      24      59
    1      25      60
    1      26      61
    1      27      62
    1      28      63
    1      29      64
    1      30      65
    2      1       10
    2      2       11
    2      3       12
    2      4       13
    2      5       14
    2      6       15
    2      7       16
    2      8       17
    2      66      80
    2      67      81
    2      68      82
    2      69      83
    2      70      84
    2      71      85
    2      72      86
```

what is the easiest and fastest way to accomplish this, knowing that the original table contains thousands of records

Comment: **Always** include your Oracle database version. If you don't know it, run `select banner from v$version`. Report the **full** version number, for example 12.2.0.1.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `lateral` clause, used below, is available since Oracle 12.1. For older versions, a `connect by` hierarchical query is still probably the fastest, but it will need to be written with a bit more care (and it **will** be slower than using `connect by` in a lateral join).

Of course, the big assumption is that the inputs are always in the form number-dash-number, and that the difference between the upper and the lower bound is the same in the two columns, for each row. I am not even attempting to check for that.

```
select t.id, l.field_1, l.field_2
from   mytable t, 
       lateral (select to_number(substr(field_1, 1, instr(field_1, '-') - 1))
                              + level - 1 as field_1,
                       to_number(substr(field_2, 1, instr(field_2, '-') - 1))
                              + level - 1 as field_2
                from   dual
                connect by level <= 
                   to_number(substr(field_1, instr(field_1, '-') + 1))
                 - to_number(substr(field_1, 1, instr(field_1, '-') - 1)) + 1
               ) l
;
```

Answer (score 1):

One option uses a recursive query. Starting 11gR2, Oracle supports standard recursive common table expressions, so you can do:

```
with cte(id, field_1, field_2, max_field_1, max_field_2) as (
    select 
        id, 
        to_number(regexp_substr(field_1, '^\d+')), 
        to_number(regexp_substr(field_2, '^\d+')),
        to_number(regexp_substr(field_1, '\d+$')), 
        to_number(regexp_substr(field_2, '\d+$'))
    from mytable
    union all
    select
        id,
        field_1 + 1,
        field_2 + 1,
        max_field_1,
        max_field_2
    from cte
    where field_1 < max_field_1
)
select id, field_1, field_2 from cte order by id, field_1
```

This assumes that intervals on the same row have always the same length, as showned in your sample data. If that's not the case, you would to explain how you want to handle that.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=fe150ec0960bbf1f235439102c5f72fa)**:

```
ID | FIELD_1 | FIELD_2
-: | ------: | ------:
 1 |       1 |       1
 1 |       2 |       2
 1 |       3 |       3
 1 |       4 |       4
 1 |       5 |       5
 1 |      20 |      55
 1 |      21 |      56
 1 |      22 |      57
 1 |      23 |      58
 1 |      24 |      59
 1 |      25 |      60
 1 |      26 |      61
 1 |      27 |      62
 1 |      28 |      63
 1 |      29 |      64
 1 |      30 |      65
 2 |       1 |      10
 2 |       2 |      11
 2 |       3 |      12
 2 |       4 |      13
 2 |       5 |      14
 2 |       6 |      15
 2 |       7 |      16
 2 |       8 |      17
 2 |      66 |      80
 2 |      67 |      81
 2 |      68 |      82
 2 |      69 |      83
 2 |      70 |      84
 2 |      71 |      85
 2 |      72 |      86
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `cross join` with generated values as follows:

```
SELECT ID, 
       to_number(regexp_substr(field_1, '[0-9]+',1,1)) + column_value - 1 AS FIELD_1, 
       to_number(regexp_substr(field_2, '[0-9]+',1,1)) + column_value - 1 AS FIELD_2
  FROM your_table
cross join
     table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
                         connect by level <= 
                                 to_number(regexp_substr(field_1, '[0-9]+',1,2)) 
                                 - to_number(regexp_substr(field_1, '[0-9]+',1,1)) 
                                 + 1
                        ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
ORDER BY 1,2
```